# Convertir un logIn a logOut despues de logearse(Sin cambiar de pagina)

Tags: php, css, html5

Tengo una pagina html y lo que quiero es que al logearme en la misma pagina se oculte el link de logIn y aparezca el del logOut. Como podria hacerlo?

```
<div id='page-wrap'>
<header class='main' id='h1'>
<span class="right"><a href='../PHP/signUp.php'>SignUp</a> </span>
<span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href="../PHP/logout">LogOut</a> </span>
<span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href='../PHP/logIn.php'>LogIn</a> </span>
```

Lo que yo estaba haciendo antes era al logearme ir a otra pagina pero lo que quiero hacer ahora es que la misma pagina cambie.

---

@Francisco Romero lo que necesito es que sin cambiar de pagina se me actualice el link de logIn a logOut y para eso tengo entendido que tengo que usar AJAX. 
Respecto a lo que tengo hecho es esto:

```
<?php 
    if($_SESSION["login"]){
        echo "<span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href="logout">LogOut</a> </span>";
        echo "<span> Anonimo </span>";
    }else{
        echo "<span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href='logIn.php'>LogIn</a> </span>";
        echo "<span> Erabiltzailea : <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?> </span>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Creo que para eso necesitarás de Ajax. Con PHP solo lo puedes realizar en la parte del servidor, lo que conlleva a refrescar la página. Usas javascript o jquery?

Answer (score 3):

Una de las soluciones que puedes realizar es crear una variable de sesión en tu fichero `logIn.php`, p.ej: `$_SESSION["logueado"] = true;` y después realizar una  condición que muestre uno u otro botón según si un usuario está logueado o no.

```
<?php 
   if($_SESSION["logueado"]){
?>
    <span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href="../PHP/logout">LogOut</a> </span>
<?php 
   }else{
?>
    <span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href='../PHP/logIn.php'>LogIn</a> </span>
<?php 
   }
?>
```

**NOTA 1:** En ambos ficheros (tanto en el que creas como en el que recuperas la variable de sesión) tendrás que utilizar la sentencia `session_start()` al inicio de cada uno de los ficheros para poder utilizar las variables de sesión.

**NOTA 2:** En el fichero `logout.php` tendrías que eliminar la variable de sesión ya que quieres indicar que el usuario ha salido de la página. Para ello, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
unset($_SESSION['logueado']);
```

Comment: No me funciona podrias ser mas especifico?

Comment: @UnaiLopez ¿Que es lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Está bien lo que hiciste hasta ahora solo te falto en el documento que tenias tu `if else` colocar `session_start()`

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php 
    if($_SESSION["logueado"]){
?>
        <span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href="../PHP/logout">LogOut</a> </span>
<?php 
    }else{
?>
    <span class="right" style="display:none;"><a href='../PHP/logIn.php'>LogIn</a> </span>
<?php 
}
?>
```